# Yandex maps, добавить балун

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api

Есть yandex maps, хочу добавить всплывашку к точке(балун), не получается, в примерах какая - то ерунда
Есть `mapView!!.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(petersburgPoint)` так я добавляю точки, petersburgPoint - `val petersburgPoint = Point(petersburg.latitude, petersburg.longitude)`. Хочу чтобы появлылось всплывабщее окно и там ,например, показывался Санкт-Петербург

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «Как задать хороший вопрос?» для прояснения ситуации. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: поправил,посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: понял , спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В песочнице есть пример определения адреса клика на карте с использованием обратного геокодирования: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

Если координаты точки известны заранее, то код в примере выше можно упростить:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var coords = [59.93772, 30.313622], // ваши координаты
        myPlacemark,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: coords,
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

        myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        getAddress(coords);

    // Создание метки.
    function createPlacemark(coords) {
        return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            iconCaption: 'поиск...'
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
            draggable: false
        });
    }

    // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
    function getAddress(coords) {
        myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
        ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

            myPlacemark.properties
                .set({
                    // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                    iconCaption: [
                        // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                        firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                        // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                        firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                    ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                    // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                    balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
                });
        });
    }
}
```